# SQL - Getting the average score of all one-to-many relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a one-to-many relationship between Questions and Scores.  My table setup is:

```
Table Question:
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    question varchar(255);

Table Score:
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    score float,
    question_id int foreign key
```

For each question, I want to find the average score, so I need `question` from the Question table, and I need to calculate the average.

I tried:

```
SELECT Question.question, SUM(Score.score)/COUNT(Score.question_id) FROM `Question` INNER JOIN `Score` WHERE Question.id = Score.question_id;
```

But it's only returning the first question and average.  You can see it in action at [my SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da906/2).

What do I need to modify for it to return all questions and their average scores?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you forgot to add `GROUP BY` clause,

```
SELECT ...
FROM...
GROUP BY Question.question
```

and you can also alternatively use `AVG()`

```
SELECT  Question.question, 
        AVG(Score.score) AS average  
FROM    Question INNER JOIN Score 
            ON Question.id = Score.question_id
GROUP   BY Question.question
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da906/5)

Comment: please also use the standard syntax of `JOIN`. more on this link: [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Ah, yeah... didn't realize I left out the `ON`