# Translating a MySQL query to DQL

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, dql

This question is a follow-up to what I asked (and received a working answer to) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16868157/399584).

How can I translate this into DQL?  The docs on JOINs is a bit confusing to me.

---

EDIT:

I'm using Doctrine with Symfony2, and have the following entities:

Question:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Question", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="id_idx", columns={"id"})})
 */

class Question
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string question
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="question", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @var array scores
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Score", mappedBy="question")
     */
    private $scores;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Score:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Score", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="id_idx", columns={"id"})})
 */

class Score
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var integer $question
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question", inversedBy="scores")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="question_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @var float score
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="score", type="float")
     */
    private $score;

    // getters and setters
}
```

I've used the following query:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT q AS question, AVG(s.score) AS average FROM CMSBundle:Question q JOIN q.scores s GROUP BY q.id ORDER BY q.id ASC');

$questions = $query->getResult();
```

However, with that query, $questions contains 0 elements.  I'm not getting any errors, either (at least, none that PhpStorm can find in its debugger).

With a lack of feedback on why I'm getting literally nothing from my query, I'm at a bit of a loss.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You would be wise to edit this and put the actual SQL in to this question.

Comment: Would also need to know the names of your Doctrine classes and fields, and how you wanted the data to come out.  As most DQL hydrates in the 'pure' fashion, objects only, but do you want a mixed hydration, objects and the averages, or just the ids and the averages for later use?

Comment: You'll find it'll be something like `SELECT q, AVG(s.score) FROM Question q JOIN q.score GROUP BY q.id`, which will give you a [mixed hydration](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#pure-and-mixed-results).

Comment: Edited with a lot more info.

Comment: `CMSBundle:Question` usually classes are given with slashes.  Looks alright generally, haven't used aliases with it myself.

Comment: Aliases seem to work by default with Symfony2.  Haven't had any problems with other `Bundlename:Entity` references in other queries.

Comment: Presumably there's no error generated by `createQuery()`, have you tried echoing `$query->getSQL()` and running it in an SQL console to see what comes up - no results usually means there is no matching data.

Comment: Check that JOIN - it is the only filter-like bit in your query. Run a summary without JOIN just to make sure there is some output.

Comment: Problem is, I'm an idiot who neglected to insert score data. :P    @Orbling, make some sort of relevant answer and I'll give you the points, since you've tried helping me from the start.

Comment: @KevinM1: You should just be able to delete the question, save the rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember coming across this exactly problem just last week. I spent a long time figuring out how do this and I managed to come up with the following DQL. Add a new method to your Question's repository class.

I've had to tweak my own code to match the question so no guarantee it work work but give it a try.

```
<?php

namespace Acme\CMSBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class QuestionRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function findAverageScoresPerQuestion()
    {
        $dql = <<<SQL
SELECT
    q question,
    AVG(s.score) average
FROM
    Acme\CMSBundle\Entity\Question q,
    Acme\CMSBundle\Entity\Score s
WHERE
    s.question = q.id
GROUP BY q.id
ORDER BY q.id ASC
SQL;

        $q = $this->_em->createQuery($dql);

        return $q->getResult();
    }
}
```

When rendering the result with Twig from the controller, the `question` properties are nested one level deeper

```
public function averageScoresAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $questions = $em->getRepository('AcmeCMSBundle:Question')->findAverageScoresPerQuestion();

    return $this->render('AcmeCMSBundle:Question:questions.html.twig', array(
        'questions' => $questions
    ));
}
```

In `questions.html.twig`

```
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Question
        <th>Average Score
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for q in questions %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ q.question.question }}
        <td>{{ q.average }}
      </tr>
    {% else %}
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">No results found
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```